# Move x-axis to pass through given y-axis value in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, axis-labels

I have the following chart:

```
let ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var datasets = [
  {
    data: [1.1, 0.8, 1.2, 1.1, 0.7],
    type: "line",
  },
];
var options = {};
var data = {labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], datasets: datasets};
var config = {type: "line", data: data, options: options};
var chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

which when renders shows the x-axis starting on a y-axis value of `0.6`. Is there a way to have the x-axis running through a y-axis value of `1`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I understand your problem well. In case you want to your y-axis value start with **1** instead of **0.6** there is way to tell Chart.js by passing some options about these values.
Modifying your options definition like this:

```
var options = {
  scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              min: 1
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

should do the tick!

Check out the [related documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration) where you can find some more options and examples how to use them ;)